# Sort search results in django

Tags: python, django

I have a function that returns a queryset and an html file with the results,

```
def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        sort = '-date'
        post_list = Post.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) #| Q(title__icontains=query) another field
        ).order_by(sort)
        return post_list
```

form:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
      <input class="form-control" name="q" type="text" placeholder="חפש מאמרים">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-sm-0" type="submit">חפש</button>
    </form>
```

In the template for the results I want there to be a couple of links to sort by date, votes etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a little get form that adds the relevant order by a query param named order.

```
?order_by=-date
?order_by=score
?order_by=author
```

and get these in the view with `request.GET.get("order_by")`

or you can use a library like:

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html

Comment: I did it, but then post_list is none

Comment: <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q={{query}}/?order_by=-votes">votes</a>

Comment: For multiple query params it is & not / `?foo=bar&abc=xyz`

Answer (score 1):

Please don't allow arbitrary sorting: this is a security vulnerability since users can sort for example on the gender of the author of a `Post`, which might be data you want to protect. You should work with a list of acceptable choices, so:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    sort = self.request.GET.get('order_by', '-date')
    if sort not in ['date', '-date', 'votes', '-votes']:
        sort = '-date'
    return Post.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(title__icontains=query)
    ).order_by(sort)
```

The url then should look like:

```
<a href="{% url 'search' %}?q={{ query|urlencode }}&amp;order_by=-votes">votes</a>
```

with `'search'` the name of the path that points to this view.

---

> **Note**: It might be worth to take a look at [**`django-filter`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) to do filtering based on a `QueryDict` in a more declarative way.